# How do I extract part of the basepath to a variable

Tags: apigee

I have a Proxy defined with a basepath of /v1.0/stores
and a resource with a path of /*/address/validate**

I have an ExtractVariables policy that has

```
<URIPath>
   <Pattern ignoreCase="false">/{storeid}/{service}/*.{format}</Pattern>
   <Pattern ignoreCase="false">/{storeid}/{service}/**/*.{format}</Pattern>
</URIPath>
```

How do I assign the "v1.0" from the proxy.basepath to {version}?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path being evaluated using `<URIPath>` configuration is actually `proxy.pathsuffix` and that contains everything after the basepath.  Try this configuration in the policy:

```
<Variable name="proxy.basepath">
  <Pattern>/{version}/**</Pattern>
</Variable>
```

The variable being referenced, `proxy.basepath`, should be holding `/v1.0/stores`. The above pattern will extract `v1.0` and store it in the variable `version`.

Link to Apigee variables reference which describes `proxy.basepath` is located [here](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/api/variables-reference).